# How to fill in missing dates and keep running sum of values using SQL SELECT?

Tags: sql, presto

There's a table with values for certain dates:

```
   date    |    value
-------------------------
2019-01-01 |     50
2019-01-03 |     100
2019-01-06 |     150
2019-01-08 |     20
```

But what I'm hoping to do is create a time series with a running sum from the first to the last date so:

```
   date    |    value
-------------------------
2019-01-01 |     50    
2019-01-02 |     50
2019-01-03 |     150   (+100)
2019-01-04 |     150
2019-01-05 |     150
2019-01-06 |     300   (+150)
2019-01-07 |     300   
2019-01-08 |     320   (+20)
```

The only constraint is that all tables are `read only`, so I can only query them and not modify them.

Does anyone know if this might be possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the dates using arrays and `unnest()`.  The rest is a `left join` and cumulative sum:

```
select dates.dte,
       sum(t.value) over (order by dates.dte)
from (values (sequence(from_iso86001_date('2019-01-01'),
                       from_iso86001_date('2019-01-08'),
                       interval '1' day
                      )
             )
     ) v(date_array) cross join
     unnest(v.date_array) dates(dte) left join
     t
     on t.date = dates.dte;
```